# Is the Ubuntu 16.04.1 download from Canonical's Website Corrupt?

Tags: 16.04, downloads, canonical

I downloaded Ubuntu 16.04 LTS from Canonical's website, but when I tried to create a bootable USB via Rufus, it told me that ISO Image Extraction failed. I later managed to create a bootable USB via Win32 Disk Manager, but on bootup, my computer said that the file was corrupt. I then downloaded Ubuntu 16.04 LTS from Canonical's website again, but I got the same problem.

What do I do now? I have limited internet data, so should I try downloading another a flavor of Linux? If so which one? Debian looks cool to me. Mint is too Windows like. If there is anyway I can still get Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, then please let me know.

Comment: Try checking the md5 checksum of your iso against the one calculated by Ubuntu, using this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM

Comment: I did. The md5 checksum seems correct. [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/873291/iso-image-extraction-failure-rufus)

Comment: Have you downloaded the proper architecture? Is you ISO for Ubuntu 32-bit or 64-bit? What about your system? I guess you have downloaded a 64-bit version while your system uses 32-bit architecture.

Comment: @MostafaAhangarha No, I run Windows 10 64 bit, and I installed the 64 bit version.

Comment: What option have you selected in Rufus? You need UEFI/GTP. Also, if you're having trouble in making a proper USB now you'll have the exact same problem with any distro you want to try so don't. Make sure your computer works fine booting from that USB as some combos simply do not play along together (the same USB boots and installs perfectly in other PCs, other USBs work in this PC) and, after assuring the ISO is fine (md5sum) use the correct options in RUfus as above (or try the *dd* method in Rufus).

Comment: Try booting and then, if any, please edit and update your question with the **exact** error message and/or a description of what you see happening.

Answer (score 2):

The ISOs on Ubuntu's server are unlikely to be corrupt, but your download may have failed. Re-download the image, and then verify the image against the published MD5 or SHA256 sums on the download page.

You should check the hash after download by running:

```
sudo md5sum /path/to/ubuntu.iso
```

or

```
sudo sha256sum /path/to/ubuntu.iso
```

If you are on Windows download this simple checker: http://www.winmd5.com/

Comment: My md5sum values match.

Comment: did you try to use unetbootin https://sourceforge.net/projects/unetbootin it will be more better to create your iso

Comment: I used Rufus. And I don't have the USB anymore. It was my friend's :(

Comment: unetbootin is good iso creator for linux distrubtion where are you from may be i can borrow you a usb

Comment: No, Unetbootin is **not** a good tool for many newer hardware. Ubuntu ISOs are hybrid since a long time ago. That means that by far the best method is a straightforward `dd` which copies the image verbatim. MKUSB (Ubuntu) uses it perfectly and it's all I use for all Linux installers. Rufus (Windows) also can use the method but it's not the default. The default, provided the correct option is selected, as commented above, it works just as fine.

Comment: It doesn't work! I keep getting image extraction failure. I've installed 2 ISOs already. What's going on?

Comment: try CelticWarrios soulation try to write the image using dd you can do by typing #dd bs=4M if=/path/to/image.iso of=/dev/sdb or whatever